# Mysql expression to select everything from a database orde by date desc

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database which keeps jobs:

**user_job(job_id, job_title, day, month, year).** The day, month, year fields holds the expiration date for each job. Day holds values 1..31, month holds values january...december and year from 2014...2040.

I want to select * from this table order by expiration date DESC. Any idea how to write my expresion? I mean that I want to get jobs by their expiration date DESC.
This is what I have tried but not working:

```
<?php

  $get_jobs = mysql_query("select * FROM `user_job` order by `day`, `month`, `year` DESC ");

?>
```

Comment: Combine day, month, year into one `timestamp` or `datetime` column. You can then order by that one column. Not sure why you have it separated like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
select * FROM `user_job` 
order by `year` desc, 
          case when `month` = 'january' then 1 
               when `month` = 'february' then 2
               when `month` = 'march' then 3
               when `month` = 'april' then 4
               when `month` = 'may' then 5
               when `month` = 'june' then 6
               when `month` = 'july' then 7
               when `month` = 'august' then 8
               when `month` = 'september' then 9
               when `month` = 'october' then 10
               when `month` = 'november' then 11
               when `month` = 'december' then 12
          end desc,
         `day` desc
```

Comment: @user2491321: Yes, I switched day and month, It is now correct thanks to the edit of another user.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
select * FROM `user_job` order by date(concat(`year`,'-',`month` ,'-',`day`)) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this simple query.

```
select * FROM `user_job` order by STR_TO_DATE(concat(`month`,'/',`day`,'/',`year`), '%M/%e/%Y') desc
```